# Stack overflow error when loading web app from Spring property resolver

Tags: spring-mvc

It looks like there is a recursive loop in my spring set up.

I've looked in the applicationContext.xml and springapp-servlet.xml files and don't see any repeats or circular dependencies. I'm not all that familiar with spring and don't really know where to start to debug this.

Is there a way I can find out what property is being resolved?

Here's my stack dump

```
2014-10-04 00:39:45,872 [localhost-startStop-1]  ERROR             ContextLoader :     Context initialization failed
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.getJndiProperties(VersionHelper12.java:89)
at com.sun.naming.internal.ResourceManager.getInitialEnvironment(ResourceManager.java:138)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:219)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:197)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.createInitialContext(JndiTemplate.java:136)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.getContext(JndiTemplate.java:103)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:85)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate.lookup(JndiLocatorDelegate.java:38)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:77)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate.lookup(JndiLocatorDelegate.java:33)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiPropertySource.getProperty(JndiPropertySource.java:82)
at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:73)
at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:59)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.getProperty(AbstractEnvironment.java:427)
at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$1.getProperty(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:131)
at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$1.getProperty(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:128)
at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:73)
at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:59)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver$1.resolvePlaceholder(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:176)
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:146)
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:125)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:174)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:143)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveNestedPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:163)
at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:76)
at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:59)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver$1.resolvePlaceholder(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:176)
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:146)
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:125)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:174)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:143)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveNestedPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:163)
at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:76)
at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:59)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver$1.resolvePlaceholder(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:176)
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:146)
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:125)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:174)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:143)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveNestedPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:163)
at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:76)
at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:59)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver$1.resolvePlaceholder(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:176)
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:146)
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:125)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:174)
at org.springfra
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that happens since you dont have the datasource property file in your classpath or the direct values in your xml definitions where you have defined datasource or session factory